# Using Two Stored Procedure - One get , One update ; But despite records being big, but updated rows = 0, is there anything wrong with my code?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, nested-loops, procedure

Get All selected players, then for each player loop 2nd procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`adrian.ng`@`xx.xx.23.151` PROCEDURE `test_dev_00`.`LoopPlayerFirstDpt`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE thisPlayer BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE counts BIGINT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT COUNT(*), uid FROM ((SELECT dno, uid, utype, bcid, amount, remark, created, transtype, status, updated, dealremark, acode, 
actual, ddeals, ufinish, ddomain, userbank, deposituser, ischk, ano, ppid, optionid, cardnum, agentid, platform, currency, brandid 
FROM test_deposit_requisition WHERE status = 33 AND (currency = '' OR currency = 'CNY')  
ORDER BY created) UNION (SELECT id AS dno, uid, 1 AS utype, 0 AS bcid, amount, remark, created, 0 AS transtype, 
33 AS status, updated, remark AS dealremark, 0 AS acode, amount AS actual, 0 AS ddeals, 0 AS ufinish, '' AS ddomain, '' AS userbank, 
'' AS deposituser, 0 AS ischk, 0 AS ano, 0 AS ppid, 0 AS optionid, '' AS cardnum, 0 AS agentid, '' AS platform, currency, brandid 
FROM test_member_manual_adjust WHERE btype = 1234  AND (currency = '' OR currency = 'CNY') 
ORDER BY created)) x GROUP BY uid having count(*) >0 and count(*) <3 ORDER BY x.created;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;

  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO counts, thisPlayer;
    IF NOT done THEN
      CALL UpdateFirstDpt(@thisPlayer);
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

and here's the UpdateFirstDpt Procedure that were called:  (for each player, get the data, insert into table)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_dev_00.UpdateFirstDpt(IN thisPlayer BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE a, b BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE c TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED; 
  DECLARE d DECIMAL(20,8);
  DECLARE e,f INT(10) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE g TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT dno, uid, 0 as dptype, actual as amount, created, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) as updated, 0 as status FROM ((SELECT dno, uid, utype, bcid, amount, remark, created, transtype, status, updated, dealremark, acode, 
actual, ddeals, ufinish, ddomain, userbank, deposituser, ischk, ano, ppid, optionid, cardnum, agentid, platform, currency, brandid 
FROM test_deposit_requisition WHERE status = 33 AND uid = thisPlayer AND (currency = '' OR currency = 'CNY') 
LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT id AS dno, uid, 1 AS utype, 0 AS bcid, amount, remark, created, 0 AS transtype, 
33 AS status, updated, remark AS dealremark, 0 AS acode, amount AS actual, 0 AS ddeals, 0 AS ufinish, '' AS ddomain, '' AS userbank, 
'' AS deposituser, 0 AS ischk, 0 AS ano, 0 AS ppid, 0 AS optionid, '' AS cardnum, 0 AS agentid, '' AS platform, currency, brandid 
FROM test_member_manual_adjust WHERE btype = 1234 AND uid = thisPlayer  AND (currency = '' OR currency = 'CNY') 
LIMIT 1)) x ORDER BY x.created desc limit 1;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;

    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO test_deposit_pool(dno,uid,dptype,amount,created,updated,status) VALUES(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
   
  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

i got updated rows = 0, what went wrong? The main select queries u do not have to check as it is cross checked already from my side to call individually and there are big amounts of data returned, in terms of **logic**, is there something im missing that causes updating empty rows? Thank youu

p,s: my function mainly is getting all players from LoopPlayerFirstDpt() , then at UpdateFirstDp(), for each **player** , get their data (1 row), and insert into the respective table.

Comment: Is `autocommit` enabled?

Comment: @Abra Yes already enabled.